# "The file is corrupt and cannot be openned." DOCM JSP

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jsp

I have a problem with download documents .docm on my jsp server. When i download the document and openned appears este mensaje:

"The file is corrupt and cannot be openned."

```
    String nombreWord = request.getParameter("nombre_Word").trim();     
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + nombreWord + ".docm");
    PrintWriter outs = response.getWriter();
    String Salida= request.getParameter("datos_Word");
    outs.println(Salida);
```

I need help please.